# How do I generalize these for loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have written a code that works well for me, however it is hard coded. My only problem with it is I would like to make it more general. I appreciate any kind of help. I will post the piece of code I have written and explain what I would like to generalize.First let us assume we have a `cell` we call it `H` whose 
size is `2x4` and with each entry being a matrix of dimension `[12x50]`. I have the following code which I would like to update assuming we have the cell `H` being of any size `NrxNt`

```
H1=[];
H2=[];
for i=1:1:50
    for j=1:4:12
        H1= [H1,H{1,1}(j,i),H{1,2}(j+1,i), H{1,3}(j+2,i),H{1,4}(j+3,i)];
        H2= [H2,H{2,1}(j,i),H{2,2}(j+1,i), H{2,3}(j+2,i),H{2,4}(j+3,i)];
     end
end
```

My problems are

1) I would like to generalize the first dimension of the cell matrix to a general value `Nr` instead of being 2 and accordingly update it in the `for` loops

2) I would like to generalize the second dimension of the cell matrix to a general value `Nt` instead of being 4 and accordingly update it in the `for` loops

3) I would like to generalize the variables `H1` and `H2` to any number of variables equal to `Nr`

I appreciate any help and sugggestions

Thank you.

Comment: I feel this would be easier if H was a 3D matrix rather than a cell array of matrices...

Comment: So do you think there is no way to generalize it? @wolfie